# How to I break an XML node into 2 using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML node with a child element that I need to break up into two
Something like this

```
<node margin="5pt" color="red">with some text and <seperator/> where the element continues</node>
```

The result should be

```
<node margin="5pt" color="red">with some text and </node>
<node margin="5pt" color="red">where the element continues</node>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following XSLT 1.0 stylesheet will split up the content and produce separate `node` elements with the content of the `text()` that are siblings to the `seperator` element (which is [mis-spelled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/separator))

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="seperator"/>

    <xsl:template match="node/text()[preceding-sibling::seperator or following-sibling::seperator]">  
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="../@*|."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Great thank you! and thanks for the bringing up the spelling mistake